# Display the number of user comments

Tags: functions, comments, author

I would like to display, on the author/user/contributor page, the number of comments the user has posted, and the number of comments he has received on his posts. Is it possible?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Got some idea from [here](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/comment/display-user-comment-count-next-to-username/).
User's comments have posted

```
<?php
function commentCount() {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM ' . $wpdb-comments. ' WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() . '"');
    echo $count . ' comments';
}

commentCount();
?>
```

I don't have any idea for comments that user got from their posts. Might be use custom [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) query too, where post_id is array of their post id.