# User's Comments Number: Storing it in a meta field for different uses

Tags: functions, comments, user-meta

As I am building a new website where tracking users' information is key to engage, etc..., I found it important to be able to store users' number of counts as a meta.

The main reason for storing the information in users' meta is to allow for **smoother integration** with external services. In my case, I already have a plugin that pushes users' meta to an external e-mail marketing service. There, I plan to run automated campaigns that include sending thank you and other gifts or perks based on the number of published comments for a user.

Here is the code I am currently using to store the number of comments made by users. This is based on [this other post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22382/display-the-number-of-user-comments). I am no coder and I know there are areas for improvement, but I thought I would post this code here incase others are interested in doing this. Therefore, this could be their starting code.

**If anyone have optimized/improved versions of the code, please do share :).**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this within a plugin, but it can be used within your theme's function file.

```
// Create field to track users' comments numbers                                    
function display_educadme_user_comments_number($user_id) {
            if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    global $wpdb;
                    $user_comments_number = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() . '"');

                        ?>                          
                            <h3><?php _e('Participation in the website'); ?></h3>
                            <table class="form-table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    <label for="user_comments_number">
                                    <?php _e('Number of comments'); ?>
                                    </label></th>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="user_comments_number" value="<?php echo $user_comments_number ?>">
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php

                } else {}
        }

// Update users' comments numbers
function save_educadme_user_comments_number($user_id) {
            if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    if ( !is_super_admin() )
                    return FALSE;
                    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_comments_number', $user_comments_number );                     
                } else {}
    }

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'display_educadme_user_comments_number' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'display_educadme_user_comments_number' );
add_action( 'profile_update', 'save_educadme_user_comments_number' );
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_educadme_user_comments_number' );
```